# how could i upload pdf file using Codeigniter

Tags: pdf, codeigniter-3

how could i upload pdf file using codeigniter? can anyone sharing the code? it would be great help for me. I searched but not didn't get the specific solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//////////in controller

```
public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';//file save path
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'pdf';
            $config['max_size']             = 100000;


            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
    }
```